# Array subscript operator on a Matrix

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to overload the Array subscript operator on a Matrix, however I'm getting an error that I can't understand. The CMazeSquare && operator[] (const tuple &other); is meant to access the CMazeSquare grid** which a matrix of CMazeSquares. I would like to be able to access the CMazeSquare object just by saying grid[someTuple]

```
CMaze.h:61:17: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&&’ token
     CMazeSquare && operator [] (const tuple &other);
                 ^
```

I can't for the life of me understand what is wrong here. Please help.

```
#ifndef CMAZE_H
#define CMAZE_H

struct tuple
{
    short x;
    short y;
    tuple();
    tuple(const tuple &other);
    tuple(short X, short Y);
    tuple operator + (const tuple &other);
};

class CMaze
{
    public:

    private:
    struct CMazeSquare
    {
        CMazeSquare ();
        void Display (ostream & outs);
        sType what;
        bool vistited;


    };

    CMazeSquare ** grid;
    CMazeSquare && operator [] (const tuple &other); //<- This is the problem
};

#endif
```

I'm thinking the implementation of the operator would look something like this:

```
//in CMaze.cpp
CMaze::CMazeSquare && CMaze::operator [](tuple &other)
{
    return this[other.x][other.y];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't && means the logical and operator?

Comment: @H.Jabi no. here it's part of the type and denotes a reference

Comment: is `addWalls` and other stuff like that part of the problem? Please **reduce your code** to a [MCVE]

Comment: @bolov I always thought reference is declared with one `&`. Long term distance from c++, pretty bad for myself :(

Comment: @bolov thanks, Changed.

Comment: @Iramch congratulation and thank you. You are one of the few cases where the OP actually managed to trim the code to a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

This is how `operator[]` is usually overloaded:

```
CMazeSquare& operator[] (const tuple &other)
{
   return grid[other.x][other.y];
}

const CMazeSquare& operator[] const (const tuple &other)
{
   return grid[other.x][other.y];
}
```

---

There a few problems with your code:

First, the definition doesn't match the declaration:

```
CMazeSquare && operator [] (const tuple &other);
vs
CMaze::CMazeSquare && CMaze::operator [](tuple &other)
```

Note the `const` missing in the definition parameters

Then you can't say `this[...]`. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Lastly why are you trying to return an rvalue reference? You need 2 overloads one for const returning a const lvalue reference and one for mutable returning a mutable reference.

---

the error you got I suppose is because you don't compile in `C++11` and the compiler doesn't understand `&&`.